# выборка из базы данных строк с нарушением последовательности

Tags: sql, база-данных, oracle, plsql

Допустим есть клиентская база депозитных счетов, есть таблица с историями операций по счету, где есть поля "баланс", "сумма операции", "порядковый номер операции по счету" и "дата совершения операции".

Необходимо найти строки операций по которым произошли нарушения арифметической последовательности операции.

Т.е., баланс не соответствует нужному числу с учетом суммы операций.

И еще найти такие строки, по которым дата операции с меньшим номером больше даты операции с большим номером.

Comment: покажите примерные значения. 4-5 строки и что значить не соответствие баланса

Comment: @Sergey4590 Да, приведите данные. С нарушениями и без. А вообще, если еще не поздно, меняйте архитектуру базы. Нельзя вычисленный баланс хранить в каждой записи. Это ведет к несостыковкам и необходимости подобных запросов, как вы сейчас просите. Баланс должен быть равен просто сумме всех операций, при желании, для экономии времени ведомый триггерами как единичное поле в клиенте

Comment: @Mike в некоторых банковских структурах они требуют что бы фиксировалось баланс на тот момент времени. Вот и возможно у них тоже такая структура базы. Если сумму брать, то они потом не смогут найти транзакцию который удалился (или удалили нарошно).

Comment: @Sergey4590 Приведите  структуру таблиц и данные

Comment: @Saidolim Да, согласен. хотя delete можно триггерами запретить как класс. Хочешь исправить ошибочную операцию, вставляй операцию "сторно".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы не привели структуру таблиц и данные. Применим экстрасенсорные способности. Структура таблицы такая:

```
create table table1(
 usr_id int,  -- Клиент
 opnum int,   -- Порядковый номер операции, начиная с 1
 opval int,   -- Сумма операции
 balance int, -- Текущий баланс
 dt date      -- Дата операции
);
```

Баланс в любой строке равен сумме всех операций по данному клиенту с первой по текущую. Номера операций идут подряд +1 к предыдущей записи данного клиента, начиная с 1.

Тестовые данные:

```
insert into table1 values(1,1,100,100,sysdate-12);
insert into table1 values(1,2,100,200,sysdate-11);
insert into table1 values(1,3,-30,170,sysdate-9);   -- Ошибка даты
insert into table1 values(1,4,300,470,sysdate-10);  -- Ошибка номера, ошибка суммы
insert into table1 values(2,1,100,100,sysdate-12);
insert into table1 values(2,3,100,200,sysdate-11);  -- Пропущен номер операции "2"
insert into table1 values(2,4,100,300,sysdate-10);
insert into table1 values(2,5,50,350, sysdate-9);
insert into table1 values(2,6,-150,200,sysdate-8);
insert into table1 values(2,7,100,250,sysdate-7);   -- Ошибка в сумме
```

Запрос:

```
select * from
 (
  select a.*,
     (lag(opnum,1,0) over(partition by usr_id order by dt))+1 n_opnum, -- Ожидаемый номер
     sum(opval) over(partition by usr_id order by dt) n_balance        -- Ожидаемая сумма
    from table1 a
   order by usr_id,dt    -- Для наглядности, на правильность работы не влияет
 )
where n_opnum!=opnum     -- Номер операции не соответствует
   or n_balance!=balance -- Сумма не соответствует
```

Результат:

```
USR_ID  OPNUM   OPVAL   BALANCE DT                  N_OPNUM N_BALANCE
1       4       300     470     28.01.2016 18:27:37 3       500
1       3       -30     170     29.01.2016 18:27:37 5       470
2       3       100     200     27.01.2016 18:27:37 2       200
2       7       100     250     31.01.2016 18:27:37 7       300
```

Вот примерно так. Используются оконные функции, незаменимые в таких случаях. `lag(opnum,1,0)` дает значение поля `opnum` из предыдущей записи в *окне*, 0 - для первой записи в *окне*. `sum(opval) over(order by)` - нарастающая сумма opval в *окне*.

*Окно* в таких функциях можно задавать [различными способами](http://www.interface.ru/oracle/anal-itiv.htm). В данном случае мы используем `partition by` что бы окно было в пределах одного клиента и применяем `order by` для указания порядка операций в пределах клиента.